# how to fix this symbol ' is being displayed as &#39 in angular 2 application

Tags: javascript, html, angular, kendo-grid, jql

i have an angular application which is making api call when i click on a name displayed in grid table. the names are getting displayed wrong as wherever i have ' is displayed as &#39. i fixed it by using 
. but the jql query formed behind the scenes is still having name as "christopher O&#39 Hara" due to which the query breaks and proper page is not getting displayed. any ideas for how to solve this. [img of jql query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2T4B.png)

html -

```
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        {{gridTitle}}
    </div>
    <div class="gadget-body">
        <kendo-grid #grid [kendoGridBinding]="gridData" >
            <kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let column of columns" [field]="getColumnTitle(column)" [title]="getColumnTitle(column)" [width]="getColumnWidth(column)">
                 <template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column="column">
                    <span [title]="column.title" >{{column.title}}</span>
                </template>
                <template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
                    <span *ngIf="column !== 'Percentage'">  
                    <span  style="color:#3b73af;cursor:pointer">    
                      <span [class.twoDimGrid]="column === header">                      
                       <span (click)="rowItemClick(dataItem, column)">                 
                   <!-- {{dataItem[column] }}changed to decode the html content from database -->
                    <span [innerHTML]="dataItem[column]"></span>      
                       </span>
                    </span>
                    </span>
                    </span>
                    <progressbar *ngIf="column === 'Percentage'" [max]="100" [value]="dataItem[column]">
                        <span style="color:white; white-space:nowrap;">{{dataItem[column]}}% </span>
                    </progressbar>
                </template>
                <template kendoGridFooterTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
                    <span style="color:#3b73af;cursor:pointer">    
                      <span [class.twoDimGrid]="column.field === header"> 
                    <span (click)="footerClick( column)" >
                  {{total[column.field]}}
                    </span>
                    </span>
                    </span>
                </template>
            </kendo-grid-column>
        </kendo-grid>
    </div>
</div>

component.ts 

      ngOnInit() {
        this.columns = [];
        this.gridTitle = this.twoDimensionalGridInfo.Name; console.log(this.gridTitle);
        this.baseJql = this.twoDimensionalGridInfo.jql; console.log( this.baseJql);
        this.type = this.twoDimensionalGridInfo.type;  console.log(this.type);
        this.summary = this.twoDimensionalGridInfo.summary; console.log(this.summary);
        if (this.summary) {
            this.fields = this.summary.split('|');
            this.y = this.fields[0]; console.log(this.fields[0]); console.log(this.y);
            this.x = this.fields[1]; console.log(this.x); console.log(this.fields[1]);
        }
        let dataItem = this.gridData[0]; 
        if (dataItem) {
            var keys = Object.keys(dataItem);   console.log(keys);
            this.header = keys[0]
        }
        for (let field in dataItem) {
            this.columns.push(field); console.log(field);
        } 
        console.log(dataItem);

        this.total = this.gridData.reduce((sums, obj) => Object.keys(obj).reduce((s, k) => {
            k === this.header || k === 'Percentage' || (s[k] = (s[k] || 0) + +obj[k]);
            return s;
        }, sums), {});
        this.total[this.header] = "Total";
        this.total["Percentage"] = "";
    } 





    public rowItemClick(dataItem, column) {
        this.orderClause = this.baseJql.slice(this.baseJql.indexOf('ORDER'));
        if (!this.orderClause.startsWith("ORDER"))
            this.orderClause = '';
        if (column === 'Count') {
            if (dataItem[this.header] == 'No assignee' || dataItem[this.header] === 'None') {
                this.customJql = this.baseJql + ' AND "' + this.x + '" is EMPTY';
            }
            else {
                this.custombaseJql = this.baseJql;
                if (this.orderClause)
                    this.custombaseJql = this.baseJql.slice(0, this.baseJql.indexOf("ORDER"));
                this.customJql = this.custombaseJql + ' AND "' + this.x + '" = "' + dataItem[this.header] + '" ' + this.orderClause;
            }
        }
        else if (dataItem[this.header] == 'No assignee' || dataItem[this.header] === 'None') {
            this.custombaseJql = this.baseJql;
            if (this.orderClause)
                this.custombaseJql = this.baseJql.slice(0, this.baseJql.indexOf("ORDER"));
            this.customJql = this.custombaseJql + ' AND "' + this.x + '" is EMPTY' + ' AND "' + this.y + '" = "' + column + '" ' + this.orderClause;
        }
        else {
            this.custombaseJql = this.baseJql;
            if (this.orderClause)
                this.custombaseJql = this.baseJql.slice(0, this.baseJql.indexOf("ORDER"));
            if (this.x == this.y) {
                this.customJql = this.custombaseJql + ' AND "' + this.x + '"= "' + dataItem[this.header] + '"' + this.orderClause;
            }
            else
                this.customJql = this.custombaseJql + ' AND "' + this.x + '"= "' + dataItem[this.header] + '"' + ' AND "' + this.y + '" = "' + column + '" ' + this.orderClause;

        }
        this.userService.search(this.customJql);
    }
```

Comment: Don't escape your string for html, if you are using it in an other context. Include your code on: how you retrive the value and send it to the server, send it to your sql server.

Comment: @RolandStarke i have updated question with code.have a look , thnks.

Comment: The data comes from `gridData`? In there it should be `'`.

Comment: I have the impression that you actually store the text as HTML in your database. That may be correct if you need HTML (allow certain tags, etc.). If you actually need just text, store text, not HTML. As we don’t know how the data gets into your database, we can’t tell you how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create custom pipe `unescape`:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'unescape'
})
export class UnescapePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(value, 'text/html');
    return doc.documentElement.textContent;
  }

}
```

Use it in the next way:

```html
<div class="panel-heading">
        {{gridTitle | unescape}}
</div>
```

Comment: on adding above code it says, cannot find name DOMParser